# RRAS Server 2012 R2 Not Assigning Network Info or if it does not passing NAT

Tags: router, nat, windows-server-2012-r2, rras, routeros

I wouldn't bother with this for any other reason than the fact that the speeds I get are worth it.

Cable Modem (Bridge mode) - Server 2012 R2 (RRAS) - Linksys EA2700 (Bridged as Switch)

My issue is I've followed many guides and either the guide finishes saying. "congrats it should just work" but it doesn't

or it gets to the point where everything is setup and I even installed DHCP and DNS and then it's like you need AD DS (I don't want to be on a domain I have no need for one nor should I HAVE to join a domain if clearOS can route / firewall and do everything plus what a consumer grade router can just plug in and go (basically) then why is this such a stretch for Microsoft to accomplish?)

Why MUST I be a member of a domain to utilize a DHCP server that's silly. The Routing and Remote Access configuration utility is basically useless...

```
Server(local)
IPv4 Router (Checked)
Enabled IPv4 Forwarding (Checked)
Statis Address Pool (For DHCP Set but Clients do not grab addresses from it instead they self generate a private IP.)
Enable broadcast name resolution (Checked)

IPv4
General -
          WAN - (DHCP IP ADDRESS) [Public]
          LAN - (STATIC IP ADDRESS) [Forced Private using gpedit]
          Loopback - (127.0.0.1)
          Internal - (Not available)
IGMP -
          WAN - (Proxy | UP)
          LAN - (Router V3 | Querier)
          Internal - ( - | -)

NAT -
          WAN - ( Public )
          LAN - ( Private )
          Internal - ( Private )
```

Anyways I completely re-installed as trying to mess with AD DS without ever actually using it before in the past proved to be quite difficult as I am certain I had the system handing out IP's and allowing access to the WWW but then I shut down the environment and removed the temp router that was....

Cable Modem - Router - ( Server | Other PCs) so I could research while testing and I thought it was at the stage where I could finish up BUT when i rebooted the modem and turned on the system the DHCP server some how lost control of itself lost all its information and renamed itself to a 169 address (where the domain name is in the DHCP snap-in)

So any tips or anything would be great as I need it to be Windows and Not ClearOS as the router as the router will also be hosting a Windows Required service/server that needs to be before the firewall to run correctly.

For those who want to say "why not just use a normal consumer grade router (you already have two decent ones)" the answer is simple. I make out at 80-100Mb/s on those crappy consumer grade routers with my network. I require a full system to manage my routing as I've seen literally a 200+Mb/s speed increase since I switched. Plus what else would I do with this AM2 2.6Ghz x2 w/ 8GB DDR2, that has been laying unused in my basement for 2+ years.

Some of the guides I have followed:

> Server 2012 RRAS Setup and Configuration: Using Server 2012 as a
>   firewall/router
>   http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77
>
> Windows Server 2012 --- Enable RRAS as NAT Router
>   http://daviwa.blogspot.ca/2012/11/windows-server-2012-enable-rras-as-nat.html

Comment: Can't post more than two links I also followed 
"Enable RRAS as a VPN Server and a NAT Router"
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458971.aspx , but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what happened (I mean I'm a tech that can format re-install until they gets it right) but I managed to get DHCP and DNS servers to install and not bug me about domains or certificates or anything it's working now! Hallelujah

All I can suggest is if you are having the same issues as me just make sure you don't do anything even remotely close to domain authentication

(although remote access server bugged me for a domain I clicked join and it made me restart the pc, after restart it never actually joined a domain and the error message for joining (initial configuration wizard) stopped.

Answer (score -2):

This part of the configuration is not correct:

```
IGMP -
          WAN - (Proxy | UP)
          LAN - (Router V3 | Querier)
          Internal - ( - | -)
```

You should delete:

```
     WAN - (Proxy | UP)
     Internal - ( - | -)
```